# Change title button from another class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, delegates

please help how change title button from another class

The Class in which to change

```
protocol ChangeButtonDelegate: class {
    func changeButton(sender: UIButton)
}

class SubscribeVC : UIViewController {
    @IBAction func tryButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.changeButton(sender: sender)
        subscribeCheck = true
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

In this class the button to be changed

```
class OrderVC: UIViewController, ChangeButtonDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        subscribe.delegate = self
}

func changeButton(sender: UIButton) {
        orderButton.setTitle("Check", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `view.removeFromSuperview()` in your button action... are you adding `SubscribeVC` as a *child* view controller from `OrderVC`? Or are you *presenting* `SubscribeVC`?

Comment: order and subscribe i add to parent controller, SubscribeVC present

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.

If you are asking how to reach into another view controller and change the title of a button, the answer is "don't do that."

You should treat a view controller's view hierarchy as private. If you want to provide the ability to change a button title, add a method `setOrderButtonTitle(_ newTitle: String)`. In the implementation of that method, set the buttons' title to the new string Then call that method when you need to change the button title (although note that you can't change a view controller's views until after it's views have been loaded.)

Comment: i need to click on a button and change the title of the button in another controller

Comment: So do what I say, and add a method to the other view controller. You might name the method `setOrderButtonTitle(_ newTitle: String)`. In the other controller, you'd take the string button title and apply it to the button.

Comment: Note that if you are telling the other view controller to change it's button title before the view controller has been displayed, you will have to save the changed button title and apply it in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: controllers are already loaded,  how call this function?

Comment: "controllers are already loaded." I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ***presenting*** `SubscribeVC`, change your button action to:

```
@IBAction func tryButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.changeButton(sender: sender)
}
```

and change your delegate function in `OrderVC` to:

```
func changeButton(sender: UIButton) {
        orderButton.setTitle("Check", for: .normal)
        // dismiss the presented VC
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```